# React native - Can't dispatch action in component because state gets undefined

Tags: react-native, redux, react-redux

In my react native android app, when I try to dispatch an action in `BoardsScreen` or in the root of the app, the following error pops up:

[image: react native error]

However, when I remove it, the app doesn't crashes.

**`BoardsScreen.js`**

```
import React from 'react';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import { Container, Content, Text, List, Button, Icon, ListItem } from 'native-base';
import { ListView, StatusBar } from 'react-native';
import { ConfirmDialog } from 'react-native-simple-dialogs';
import ActionButton from 'react-native-action-button';

import { removeBoard } from '../actions/configurationActions';

class BoardsScreen extends React.PureComponent {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      boardDeleteDialog: false,
      secId: null,
      rowId: null,
      rowMap: null,
    };
  }

  deleteRow(secId, rowId, rowMap) {
    rowMap[`${secId}${rowId}`].props.closeRow();

    const newData = [...this.props.boards];

    newData.splice(rowId, 1);

    this.props.removeBoard(newData);

    this.setState({
      rowId: null,
      secId: null,
      rowMap: null,
      boardDeleteDialog: false,
    });
  }

  dataSource = new ListView.DataSource({ rowHasChanged: (r1, r2) => r1 !== r2 });

  render() {
    console.log(this.props.boards);
    return (
      <Container>
        <StatusBar backgroundColor="#00C853" />
        <ConfirmDialog
          title="Delete board?"
          animationType="fade"
          visible={this.state.boardDeleteDialog}
          positiveButton={{
            title: 'Delete',
            titleStyle: {
              color: '#2ecc71',
            },
            onPress: () => this.deleteRow(this.state.secId, this.state.rowId, this.state.rowMap),
          }}
          negativeButton={{
            titleStyle: {
              color: '#2ecc71',
            },
            title: 'Cancel',
            onPress: () =>
              this.setState({
                boardDeleteDialog: false,
                secId: null,
                rowId: null,
                rowMap: null,
              }),
          }}
        />
        <Content>
          {this.props.boards.length >= 1 ? (
            <List
              style={{ backgroundColor: '#D9534F' }}
              dataSource={this.dataSource.cloneWithRows(this.props.boards)}
              renderRow={data => (
                <ListItem
                  style={{ paddingLeft: 14, backgroundColor: 'transparent' }}
                  button
                  onPress={() =>
                    this.props.navigation.navigate('Board', {
                      board: data.board,
                      boardName: data.boardName,
                    })
                  }
                >
                  <Text>{data.boardName}</Text>
                </ListItem>
              )}
              renderRightHiddenRow={(data, secId, rowId, rowMap) => (
                <Button
                  full
                  danger
                  onPress={() =>
                    this.setState({
                      boardDeleteDialog: true,
                      secId,
                      rowId,
                      rowMap,
                    })
                  }
                >
                  <Icon active name="trash" />
                </Button>
              )}
              disableRightSwipe
              rightOpenValue={-75}
            />
          ) : (
            <Text>No boards added.</Text>
          )}
        </Content>
        <ActionButton
          buttonColor="#2ecc71"
          fixNativeFeedbackRadius
          onPress={() => this.props.navigation.navigate('AddBoard')}
        />
      </Container>
    );
  }
}

const mapStateToProps = state => ({
  boards: state.configurationReducer.boards,
});

const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => ({
  removeBoard: (board) => {
    dispatch(removeBoard(board));
  },
});

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(BoardsScreen);
```

**`App.js`**

```
import React from 'react';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import MainNavigator from './src/config/Router';

import { addBoardToList } from './src/actions/configurationActions';

import { Board } from './src/API';

class App extends React.PureComponent {
  componentDidMount() {
    Board.getList(true).then(response => this.parseDataFromJSONResponse(response));
  }

  parseDataFromJSONResponse(response) {
    for (let i = 0; i < response.length; i += 1) {
      this.props.addBoardToList(response[1]);
    }
  }

  render() {
    return <MainNavigator />;
  }
}

const mapStateToProps = state => ({
  boards: state.configurationReducer.boards,
});

const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => ({
  addBoardToList: (board) => {
    dispatch(addBoardToList(board));
  },
});

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(App);
```

**`configurationReducer.js`**

```
const initialState = {
  theme: 1,
  obscure: false,
  boards: [],
  boardsList: [],
};

const configurationReducer = (state = initialState, action) => {
  let newState = { ...state };

  switch (action.type) {
    case 'ADD_BOARD':
      newState = {
        boards: [...state.boards, action.payload],
      };

      return newState;
    case 'REMOVE_BOARD':
      newState = {
        boards: action.payload,
      };

      return newState;
    case 'ADD_BOARD_TO_LIST':
      newState = {
        boardsList: [...state.boardsList, action.payload],
      };

      return newState;
    default:
      return state;
  }
};

export default configurationReducer;
```

**`configurationActions.js`**

```
function addBoard(board) {
  return {
    type: 'ADD_BOARD',
    payload: board,
  };
}

function removeBoard(board) {
  return {
    type: 'REMOVE_BOARD',
    payload: board,
  };
}

function addBoardToList(board) {
  return {
    type: 'ADD_BOARD_TO_LIST',
    payload: board,
  };
}

export { addBoard, removeBoard, addBoardToList };
```

I really don't have a clue what is causing this, maybe it's a bug but I don't know if is react-redux fault or react native itself.

Comment: How's your reducer looks like. Also your action creators `addBoardToList` and `removeBoard `.

Comment: @Krasimir I have updated my question with the extra code.

Comment: You have a console.log in `BoardsScreen`'s render method. What's the output there.

Comment: It gives undefined.

Answer (score 0):

When you remove the board, it looks like in you reducer, you return a strange new state:

```
case 'REMOVE_BOARD':
      newState = {
        boards: action.payload,
      };

      return newState;
```

Should the boards to be an array always? I think you missed something, for example:

```
boards: state.boards.filter ((it) => it.id !== action.payload.id),
```

Comment: Yeah seems kinda strange, but actually I'm handling the removing part in `boardsScreen` then I just return an array without the deleted board.